# POST something to URL without a form?

Tags: php, forms, post

Can I `POST` something to a URL and grab the result without a form and a submit button in PHP? If so, how does that work?

Thanks,
Ryan

**UPDATE**

After a lot of trial and error, I got it to working.

I used the method described in the accepted answer, but what I had to do additionally before `POST`ing my code was:

```
$html_body = str_replace("\n", "", $html_body);
$html_body = str_replace("\t", "", $html_body);
$html_body = urlencode($html_body);
```

I had to add those for my purpose and you may not need them, but just keep it in mind.

-Ryan

Comment: Yes, using JavaScript or by making a POST request using a PHP library, but it's unsure whether that is of use for you. What is your exact situation?

Comment: I have an internal stylesheet and some HTML. The third-party said to post all of that to their URL and they will inline everything (CSS). So I will be posting all of the code and get an inlined version in return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is everything what should know about curl

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

and this will POST without form as easy as:

```
$ch = curl_init("www.example.com/curl.php?option=test");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);       
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Comment: So 'test' is the data I'm sending, right? If that data happens to be HTML/CSS code, how can I make sure the characters (&, =, etc) don't mess up by being in a query-string?

Comment: Yes - you sending variable option what equal "test"